# Vaadin Designer Tabs not correctly adding children "tab" to tabs object

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-designer

I'm using Vaadin Deisgner 14.6.1 to create some super simple tabs. However, when I try to do some simple operations in the java class (eg selecting a tab), it throws an error which indicates that the "Tabs" object does *not* have the proper children "tab" components. Here's a simple test case below. (I discovered the issue when I was trying to add a `addSelectedChangeListener()` to the tabs class and discovered that it would never fire, presumably since the "tabs" class never properly had any children.) I tried a bunch of hacks, but nothing worked. (I have in the past gotten tabs to work if I stuck purely to a programmatic approach, but I really really really like using Designer, since it saves me tonnes of times and keeps the code quite modular and clean....when it works....)

```
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-ordered-layout/src/vaadin-vertical-layout.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-tabs/src/vaadin-tabs.js';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-tabs/src/vaadin-tab.js';

class MyTabtest extends PolymerElement {

    static get template() {
        return html`
<style include="shared-styles">
                :host {
                    display: block;
                    height: 100%;
                }
            </style>
<vaadin-vertical-layout theme="spacing" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
 <vaadin-tabs theme="equal-width-tabs" id="tabs" orientation="horizontal" selected="0">
  <vaadin-tab id="tab1" selected>
    Tab one 
  </vaadin-tab>
  <vaadin-tab id="tab2">
    Tab two with a longer title 
  </vaadin-tab>
  <vaadin-tab id="tab3">
    Tab three 
  </vaadin-tab>
 </vaadin-tabs>
 <label id="lbl1">page1</label>
 <label id="lbl2">page2</label>
 <label id="lbl3">page3</label>
</vaadin-vertical-layout>
`;
    }

    static get is() {
        return 'my-tabtest';
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            // Declare your properties here.
        };
    }
}

customElements.define(MyTabtest.is, MyTabtest);
```

and

```
package com.deepsearch.fe.tab2vizdb.fpsgraphicaldetails.spectratab.hslspectrachartandalts;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Label;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.Id;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.Tab;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.Tabs;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.templatemodel.TemplateModel;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.Tag;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.JsModule;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.polymertemplate.PolymerTemplate;

/**
 * A Designer generated component for the my-tabtest template.
 *
 * Designer will add and remove fields with @Id mappings but
 * does not overwrite or otherwise change this file.
 */
@Route("tabtest")
@Tag("my-tabtest")
@JsModule("./src/my-tabtest.js")
public class MyTabtest extends PolymerTemplate<MyTabtest.MyTabtestModel> {

    @Id("tabs")
    private Tabs tabs;
    @Id("tab1")
    private Tab tab1;
    @Id("tab2")
    private Tab tab2;
    @Id("tab3")
    private Tab tab3;
    @Id("lbl1")
    private Label lbl1;
    @Id("lbl2")
    private Label lbl2;
    @Id("lbl3")
    private Label lbl3;

    /**
     * Creates a new MyTabtest.
     */
    public MyTabtest() {
      //  tabs.setSelectedTab(tab2); //throws error!
        tabs.addSelectedChangeListener(e -> {
            System.out.println("A tab got selected!"); //this never fires!!!!
        });
    }

    /**
     * This model binds properties between MyTabtest and my-tabtest
     */
    public interface MyTabtestModel extends TemplateModel {
        // Add setters and getters for template properties here.
    }
}
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to capture a tab select event -- but it doens't seem to work when the tabs are created in Designer....is this true on Vaadin's side too? (ie is this reproducible?)

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an unfortunate limitation of the component mapping to elements defined in a template. When mapping to Java, the parent-child relationships are not preserved and thus the `tabs` component does not realize that the `tab` is one of its child components.

See https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/7622

The way to make it work would be to create the `Tabs` and `Tab` instances in Java and the rest in Designer.